# Parallels doesn't recognize Windows 8 Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, parallels-desktop

I just upgraded my OSX to 10.8.3 and installed Windows 8 via Bootcamp.
For some reasons Parallels (8.0.18354) doesn't recognize this Bootcamp partition. It doesn't show up in the Parallels Wizard used to create a new virtual machine.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

I have searched high and low for this one.. turns out that there is a way to manually configure a VM from your bootcamp partition to appear within Parallels running in OSX even if the option to use an existing windows installation does not get displayed.

Check this out - http://kb.parallels.com/en/112941

Essentially what you're doing is pointing a new parallels VM file to the partition on the HDD/SSD that has the windows boot loader.