# Paralells Reports Missing Operating System with Windows 10 bootcamp Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, parallels-desktop, windows

I've installed Windows 10 Release Candidate on a brand new SSD drive. My Windows Bootcamp partition boots and runs correctly, but tends to crash ocassionaly. I believe this is due to bootcamp drivers that haven't been updated for Windows 10.

I've heard reports that running this setup through Parallels should resolve these crashes. When I open Paralells, however, I don't see the (typical and easy) bootcamp option:

[image: Parallels screenshot]
(Notice that there is no bootcamp option)

After some searching, I've found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86036/parallels-doesnt-recognize-windows-8-bootcamp) that links to [an article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/112941) about setting up the VM manually. I've followed the steps, but get the following error on booting:

```
Trying to boot from SATA drive 1...
Missing Operating system
```

[image]

I've even tried choosing a few different locations (SATA 0:2 - SATA 0:3)
but am still getting the same error.

I've also followed this [Paralells support article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/122922), although I only did the first part where you run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, but am still having the same issue.

[image]

What is the issue here?

So my setup is:

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

  - Paralells Desktop 10 10.2.2 (29105) Trial

Comment: Windows 10 is not yet officially supported by Apple under Boot Camp.   You might want to look/post in [Parallels Forums - Parallels Desktop for Mac](https://forum.parallels.com/forums/parallels-desktop-for-mac.58/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around the Parallels forums, I found an [article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/122808) with the solution. You'll have to download the **volume.inf file** that they include and replace the one in `c:\windows\Inf\volume.inf`

1. boot into Boot Camp natively
2. Make backup copy of "Windows/inf/volume.inf" file.
3. Replace "Windows/inf/volume.inf" with this .inf file: http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/kcs-36651/volume.inf.

If you get an access denied errors, replace the file using Paragon (because usually there are no access permissions:

Comment: Are you sure the windows volume is bootable afterwards? I notice that the file structure is quite different. It seems there are binary chars vs the ascii format windows is using.

Comment: @Ophidian yes, I can boot it from both Bootcamp and Parallels. It's true, the files are very different, but you should not be alarmed. Notice the link to the file download comes from kb.parallels.com

Answer (score 2):

Actually, after my comment above I played around a bit and got to the same screen as the original post.

However: you should choose edit partitions. Chances are there will be 2 partitions of which the second was not selected (which was my actual windows drive).

Selecting the second partition instead of the first actually resolved it for me.

[image: Hardisk configuration in parallels]

[image: Edit partitions]